# Como remover as aspas duplas do começo e do final de uma variável em dart?

Tags: string, variáveis, flutter, dart, jwt

Fala devs, tudo certo?

Não estou conseguindo remover as aspas duplas do começo e do fim de uma variável em dart.

Faço um POST para minha Web API e recebo um Objeto JWT. Preciso apenas do valor do objeto, sem as aspas no começo e no final.

Tentei definir objJWT[1:-1] mas não deu certo.

```
var response = await http.post(url, headers: header, body: _body);

    print('Responde body ${response.body}');

    var objJWT = response.body;
    objJWT = objJWT[1:-1];
```

Exemplo do que o ${responde.body} me retorna:

```
"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MTQyNzkwOTYsImV4cCI6MTYxNDI3OTEyNn0.si7GYefm0Iism09T91u3i1Kzo5cAYFJfdx-mbrv39Ys"
```

Eu preciso que objJWT fique desta forma:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MTQyNzkwOTYsImV4cCI6MTYxNDI3OTEyNn0.si7GYefm0Iism09T91u3i1Kzo5cAYFJfdx-mbrv39Ys
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remover primeiro e último caracter de uma string:

Se você precisa remover o primeiro e último caracteres de uma String, você pode utilizar algo do tipo:

```
 String A = "123456789";
 String B = A.substring(1, A.length-1);
 print(B);  //imprime 2345678
```

Existem diversas formas de resolver, porém uma outra abordagem poderia ser usar o método `replaceAll` para substituir todas as aspas duplas por vazio. (Dado que você tenha certeza que no meio de sua String não existirão outras aspas duplas, por exemplo.)

---

- Sobre obter o valor do objeto:

Um objeto JWT consiste de 3 strings codificadas em [Base64](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), unidas por um ponto ".".

As três partes são:

- Cabeçalho (Header)
- Carga/Objeto (Payload)
- Assinatura (Signature)

Mais sobre JWT pode ser lido [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) (em inglês).

Essa divisão pode ser vista no seu exemplo de corpo de retorno:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MTQxOTI2MTcsImV4cCI6MTYxNDE5MjY0N30.xXyluFZo2DsHbdrW6R87F5Je6m64fVetW2HjqvjXh8c
|---------Cabeçalho ----------------|----------------Carga--------------------------|-----Assinatura---------------------------|
```

Acredito que você esteja interessado no conteúdo, então você precisa verificar o componente central Carga (Payload).

Para fazer isso, você pode usar um pacote pronto (uma pesquisa rápida e achei [esse](https://pub.dev/packages/jwt_decode)). Imagino que existam outros que se proponham a essa função. Isso facilitaria seu trabalho, pois usando ele você poderia:

```
import 'package:jwt_decode/jwt_decode.dart';

Map<String, dynamic> _mapResponse = Jwt.parseJwt(response.body);
```

Outra alternativa seria implementar você mesmo seu decodificador, o que não seria muito difícil visto que a biblioteca `dart:convert` já possui métodos para Base64.

Primeiramente seria necessário dividir seu corpo pelos pontos e obter somente a parte que interessa (payload):

```
String payload = response.body.split('.')[1];
```

Uma String em base64 para ser decodificada precisa ter um número de caracteres múltiplo de 4. Caso ela não tenha, precisamos completar com o caracter igual ("="). Isso pode ser feito pelo código:

```
switch (payload.length % 4) {
    case 0:
      break;
    case 2:
      payload += '==';
      break;
    case 3:
      payload += '=';
      break;
    default:
      throw Exception('String não confere com uma codificada em base64.');
  }
```

Depois, é só usar a função nativa da `dart:convert`e fazer a decodificação:

```
import 'dart:convert';
Codec<String, String> stringToBase64Url = utf8.fuse(base64Url);
String jsonDecodificado = stringToBase64Url.decode(payload);
```

Nesse momento, a variável `jsonDecodificado` conterá o json que você deseja. No seu exemplo:

```
{"iat":1614192617,"exp":1614192647}
```

Por fim, é só seguir com a criação de mapa comum de Dart:

```
Map _mapResponse = json.decode(payload);
```

O que deve obter o mapa desejado.

Observações:

- As funções que fiz aqui são só um exemplo, e por isso não tem todos os tratamentos. Por exemplo, pode-se verificar se o token JWT possui 2 caracteres de "." antes de fazer o split.
- Presumi que você só está interessado no payload. O mesmo processo pode ser aplicado nos outros campos.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Já sai do trabalho, mas pela manhã com certeza irei testar.
Desde já, grato!